# Reversible Sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Does anyone know of an algorithm for sorting that is reversible? So given this:

5,39,196,0,15,243

Sort would create:

0,5,15,39,196,243

And then reversing it without having to know any knowledge, other than perhaps which sort algorithm was used and how many iterations were run, it would go back to:

5,39,196,0,15,243

It occurred to me that bubble sort may possibly work- as long as I knew how many times the sort had to run, I could probably just reverse the steps that number of times to get back to the original. Are there any others?

This is for an experiment so time complexity isn't an issue (I don't care how slow it is).

Comment: That doesn't seem possible at all. And why would you need that? Just keep the original order noted somewhere.

Comment: How about copy the array and sort? Then you have a sorted, and the original copy. If you need to know the original position of the element after sorted, you can attach an index number to the element.

Comment: The original order is lost, of course. What I often do is sort an array of keys 0 .. length-1, and use that for sorted access.

Comment: Possibly of interest - the Burrows-Wheeler transform, used for compression, involves a reversible sort. This sounds like witchcraft until you realize that the data being sorted has special structure that enables the reversal.

Comment: Steve, I started looking into this as well, as the only other possibly reversible sort. It's a rather intelligent transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really not concerned with runtime efficiency, you can use [Permutation Sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Permutation_sort).

It will generate all permutations of the list, and check which permutation has the list ordered. If you know how many rounds you've run before you find the sorted list, you know exactly what values have been swapped to get there.

If you run it on an unsorted list and have to run 50 rounds to get to the sorted list, you'll know exactly what elements were swapped to get there and can reverse the sort.

Comment: Note that unless there is some special structure to your data that is known in advance, you can't really do better than this and still achieve the desired effect. This is because all permutations of the original list will sort to the same result, so you need to keep (the equivalent of) a number between 1 and the number of permutations. That is exactly what you keep here.
Of course, as the comments to the question suggest, you could use a better (faster) sorting algorithm and just store the whole original list, but I assume that's not what the OP was after.

Comment: I doubt this very much.  Have you actually tried it?  Generating permutations of the sorted list will give you a sequence of permutations in an order with no relation to the order of the permutations generated from the original.

Comment: @DonRoby, if you do your sort by applying all the permutations in the same order every time and just checking to see which one gave you the correct sorting, then all you would need to keep track of to reverse the process is the sorted list and which permutation successfully sorted (which you could keep by index rather than by keeping the whole permutation).

Comment: @DonRoby The algorithm is deterministic, the same number of rounds on the same list will generate the exact same permutation every time by swapping elements. You're right about my first way of expressing it though, even though the swaps are deterministic, you will have to run the exact same swaps _in the reverse order_ to get to the original.

Comment: Your rephrasing has now convinced me, though remembering the index in the list of all permutations is remembering a rather large number!  Have an upvote.

Comment: Note that "the number of iterations run" here serves as an integer which identifies a permutation of a sequence. So that's a number up to `n!`. If the array you're sorting has more than about 20 elements, then in many languages storing this number isn't significantly easier than storing some other representation of the permutation, because it won't fit in a 64 bit integer. Of course around there, "really not concerned with efficiency" means "don't need the code to run in the lifetime of the universe", so storing the output might be irrelevant anyway :-)

Comment: I understand that, but I have constraints that help, and I can do this on parallel threading model using all of the cores available. Like I said, this is for an experiment, not industry/commercial software.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a sorting algorithm makes more than n steps (usually O(nlogn)) to sort n items. This means you are better off keeping copies (which are just n < O(nlogn)).

If copies are too much (objects are too big) you can just keep an array of references (pointers or IDs) in the initial order.