# Sorting Mechanism Reversing with Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, sorting

i knew its a weird Idea to think about, i want to know if it is possible to reverse the mechanism of sorting, (i dont want to reverse the order).

for example lets say i have a random array of integers, then i sorted the array with quicksort method, now i want to go back and un-sort the array and get it back to the it was.

you may suggest i save a copy of the array, thats not what i want, think of it as a time line and have the ability to go backward or forward of sorting method.

and if it is possible please consider showing me the best way to do it with Delphi XE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just add a tag to each element to indicate its original position, or keep the original order and add a tag to indicate an element's sorted position?

Comment: Sort the indices instead

Comment: MartynA, David, thanks for the information, actually the size matters, so i dont want to duplicate or save pointers, i searched again and found this other question, its almost the same idea , [Reversible Sort algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227599/reversible-sort-algorithm?rq=1) , see the answer is talking about Permutation Sort, with  this link [Permutation sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Permutation_sort), if its really deterministic then its possible, the last link has alot of examples for this method but non of them in pascal lang.

Comment: I don't want to believe that size would matter so much that you couldn't sort a list of pointers.

Comment: TLama, excuse my poor language, i didnt explain it good, i mean that i dont want to make changes in the size.

Comment: Sort the indices. Simple.

Comment: It's pretty bizarre that you want to take then result of a sort and know where you started without remembering where you started, or how you got there. You need to accept reality.

Comment: you are absolutely right David, at least we could have a number that tells the count of cycles used in sorting to help un-sort the array again, could it be done with Permutation Sort?

Comment: Why downvote this question? It's a legit request.

Comment: You aren't accepting reality. Suppose I have the following sorted list: 0,1,2,3,5. Can you tell me the order before I sorted? No. How many possible orders are there? How much space is needed to store each possible order. That's a lower bound on the space requirements.

Comment: ignore the last question David and thank very much, thanks all for the information, i will accept Remy's answer because it simply tells that its not possible.

Comment: Obviously it's not possible without remembering something. But it's certainly possible if you remember something. That's surely obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to unsort.  You have to either:

1. create a separate array that holds a copy of the values and then sort that array so that you can preserve the original array.
2. create a separate array that holds pointers/indexes to the values in the original array, and then sort the second array using the values it refers to.

Comment: thank you Remy for the answer, would you please consider looking at the comment i added up there, maybe there is a real chance of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use a function that given an array returns an array of the sorted indexes.

This way you will always have the original data and you will be able to access the data in a sorted way using something like:

```
for jIndex in ASortedIndexesArray do
  ShowMessage(AOriginalArray[jIndex]);
```

Hope this helps.

Mirko

Answer (score 2):

If you want to think of it ***as a time line and have the ability to go backward or forward of sorting method*** then organize it like a timeline - with records in a file. Save each step and you will be able to reproduce it.

If the array is of integers the indices will not help you as one index (a pointer) takes the same memory as one array element. If you lack RAM use a file to store and retrieve the array. If you use larger data structures you can create, store and retrieve indices as David suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You could log the swapping actions that quicksort (or whatever sorting algorithm you use) does to a list and then go forward and backward in that list to undo/redo these actions. Not simple to implement, but doable.

Comment: This is the right idea, and actually it's very simple. Just create a record with two integers and a generic stack that use that record type. Implement a quicksort as normal. Add one extra line of code to push the indexes of swapped elements onto the stack. Now you can roll backwards by just popping elements off the stack and reversing the operation. This will take more or less space than just saving the original array, depending on how sorted it was in the first place.